# Last modified date of external file in android

Tags: android, file, sd-card

I am developing an application in which there is one external file stored on SD card. This file is replaced from time to time. I want to know how I can detect whether the file has been replaced or not.

I tried following

```
    File file = new File("filepath");
    Date lastModDate = new Date(file.lastModified());
    Log.w("File last modified @ : ", lastModDate.toString());
```

The lastmodified method always returns the date "1970-01-01", even though the file is replaced from time to time.

Can anyone suggest a sample code which detects the external file modified.

Comment: file is replacing time to time ? then its not modification

Comment: I will check if file exits before asking for lastModified

Comment: Yes i can understand that its not modification. In this scenario how will i come to know whether the file is replaced or not ???